# Upgrade from Kotlin 1.3.31 -> 1.3.40 breaks Android build

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

If I try to upgrade to the latest Kotlin version in my Gradle project, I get the following error building my Android subproject:

```
e: /(redacted)/AndroidLauncher.kt: (8, 15): Cannot access built-in declaration 'kotlin.Unit'. Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library
```

Downgrading back to 1.3.31 builds fine. I also tried upgrading my com.android.tools.build version from 3.4.0 -> 3.4.1, but no difference.

The error makes it pretty clear that there's trouble finding the Kotlin STL. Is there some new dependency I need to add or plugin I need to apply?

Comment: Make sure that you are using the same Kotlin version for everything, including the `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"` entry in the top-level `build.gradle` file and the `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"` entry in the `dependencies` closure for your app's module. Anything else from the `org.jetbrains.kotlin` artifact group probably should get that same version as well.

Comment: I define `kotlinVersion` exactly once in my `gradle.properties`, which I then re-use everywhere else.

Comment: Hmmmm... my only other suggestion is to do the standard "in case of emergency, break glass" sorts of Android Studio fixes: clean the project (Build > Clean Project) and invalidate the caches (File > Invalidate Caches and Restart).

Comment: I'm not using Android Studio, this is a straight gradle build from the terminal. I did try a clean build, manually blew away all my build directories, and even trashed my local maven repository. Same error.

Comment: Do all of your modules actually depend on the Kotlin stdlib? Looks like this message is only shown when this is not the case: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/ed867578178e3477198cdd9a6a19526add120027 What does `./gradlew dependencies` say? Also please submit an issue to http://kotl.in/issue with a sample project to reproduce. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyBelkov My ":core" project depends on the stdlib, and each other subproject depends on that. Do I need to do more than that? Here is the project:
https://github.com/entangledloops/kotlin-gdx

Comment: Thanks, reproduced. This behavior is the result of the recently fixed problem https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19227. To make your project compile again, add the `implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))` dependency in your `android` subproject.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is the result of the recently fixed problem https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19227. Previously, some built-in declarations like `kotlin.Unit` were loaded from the compiler internals when the compiled module didn't have a dependency on the Kotlin stdlib. Currently such a situation causes the build to fail, which is a less surprising behavior.

To make your project compile again, add the `implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))` dependency in your `android` subproject.

Comment: how do we add the dependency in flutter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help for someone, I've a similar problem but going from 1.3.40 to 1.3.61 (not from 1.3.31 to 1.3.40); with Android Studio in my situation it worked this workaround:

- in Project build.gradle I've left kotlin version 1.3.61 and put gradle:3.5.0 
  instead of 3.6.1 which doesnt works. with the error in the title:

  ```
  buildscript {
      ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
      ...
      dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
           ...
      }
  ```
- in Module build.gradle I've put apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
  before apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Hope it works for others too.

Comment: That's not the same version of Kotlin as in my question, though. (Also, I didn't want to downgrade other components to fix this one, but thanks for your input.)

Comment: you're right, now I edit with better details in my answer. I put here only just for reporting my experience in case it helps someone (...and as a memo for myself too when it will happen again and I will forget this my own workaround! :D)